# AWS medialive : How to resume live stream of input A after input switching?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-media-live

How can i resolve this using boto3 sdk? Is live streaming of input A possible with input switching?

Comment: Can you possibly Edit your question to provide more details? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.